# Rails: Submit form on change

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can I get this to work?

```
<%= form_for current_user, html: {multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:brand, Brand.pluck(:company), {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}, {:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'}) %>
<% end %>
```

The goal is to submit the form on change automatically. But the code above does not work. I get an `wrong number of arguments (5 for 1..4)` error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last three arguments there are actually a hash of options. Try putting them into curly braces to make it more clear, if you like:

```
<%= f.select(:brand, Brand.pluck(:company), {
  prompt: true,
  class: 'form-control',
  onchange: 'this.form.submit()'
}) %>
```

Comment: For me I had to move my curly brackets around to this: <%= f.select(:brand, Brand.pluck(:company), {}, { class: 'form-select', onchange: 'this.form.submit()' }) %>

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Removed `{prompt:true}` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Select Helper:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

This should work with prompt also:

```
<%= f.select(:brand, Brand.pluck(:company), {include_blank: true, class: 'form-control'}, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()') %>
```

[Rails select helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7

```
    <%= f.select :city, ["Lahore", "Chicago", "Madrid"] , {include_blank: "none"} ,onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()" %>
```

with collection select

```
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all,:id,:name,{include_blank: "none"} , {onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()"} %>
```